# How to specify network interface in Java

Tags: java

I want to use a WiFi connection in my Java code. How can I use a specific  WiFi network interface in order to download files from the Internet?

In other words, how can I force java to send packets through a specific network interface?

Comment: Normally, you wouldn't care about which one it comes from - you just want the file!  _WHY_ does it need to be over a specific connection type?

Comment: @X-Zero: take for example a WiFi connection that has a route to a pay-per-volume Internet connection, against a LAN connection with a pay-per-time Internet connection. You would prefer to handle your downloads on the pay-per-time connection, if speed allows. My two cents.

Comment: @Luca - +1 - Yes, that would be a valid use case, although that should probably be specified in the original question, if something like that's the case.  Really, I'm just trying to make sure the OP isn't try to give himself a problem he may not really have.

Answer (score 14):

You can query for available network interfaces using the [`NetworkInterface`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html) class. Then you bind this interface to a Socket using the `bind()` method.

```
NetworkInterface ni = NetworkInterface.getByName("eth0");
Socket socket = new Socket();
socket.bind(ni.getInetAddresses().nextElement());
```

This is all specified in the Java tutorials: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/nifs/definition.html

Comment: when i try to send UDP packets in java it shows errors. 
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: Datagram send failed   at java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.socketSend(Native Method)
 at java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 1):

`NetworkInterface nif = NetworkInterface.getByName("bge0");`

see here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/nifs/definition.html